# ThreeJs: OrbitControls.js not woking

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I tried to use OrbitControls.js from ThreeJs. I created a folder and save files like it(Such as: 
GLTFLoader.js, OrbitControls.js..) but when i use function in them, i have errores like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoKzW.png)

I used to use other ways like using link to code (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js) and run cmd (npm install)... but it not working too.

Can you help me solve this problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are importing examples files as ES6 modules, it's not necessary to use the `THREE` namespace. When using `npm` the import looks like so:

```js
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
```

If you import the module inside a `<script type="module">` tag similar to the official `three.js` examples, use this style:

```js
import { OrbitControls } from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.114/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";
```

In both cases, you create an instance of the controls like so:

```js
const controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
```

Comment: I tried the ways you write. But not working. You can see my project [link] (https://glitch.com/~early-nimble-ship)

Comment: You are not including ES6 modules correctly. Do it like in this example: https://glitch.com/~sugary-flint-jonquil